# Roblox how can I search for a cloned item on the player

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am trying to make a change color for my name GUI but I do not know how to get the cloned GUI item inside of the player. And the problem is I am new to RBLX studio and do not know how to start with this so anything would help ;)

Comment: share some code. how do you "clone" that item?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could clone the GUI from ReplicatedStorage and place it into the player's head. You could do this by putting these lines of code in a server-side script in ServerScriptService.

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") -- If you put the GUI inside of ServerStorage you could change the service to get ServerStorage

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
  local playerTagClone = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("NameOfYourGUI"):Clone() -- Replace "NameOfYourGUI" to the GUI inside of ReplicatedStorage
  playerTagClone.Parent = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name).Head
end)
```

If you would like to search for an item you can use `ItemParent:FindFirstChild("ItemName")` -- Of course you would change the ItemParent and ItemName to what they say.

This code has not been tested, so let me know if you have any issues with the code or if you have any questions!